# Why does the font-awesome provided link not work and show horizontal bars?

Tags: html, font-awesome

[image: font-awesome icon rendered incorrectly]

I'm trying to use font awesome on my site and it's not working properly. I was sent an email and told to just paste the element in my site's header. This is the element.

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/b219f80601.js"></script>
```

I did all that but it's not working and displays as shown in the image. When I try my older code from a different account it uses `kit` instead of `use` and renders properly.

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/[redacted].js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The icon I tried to use was fas fas user

```html
<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
```

What might be happening here? Also, font-awesome did not add the `crossorigin` attribute to the newer tag.

A note: I'm also using bootstrap 5.

This is my header:

```html
<head>
   <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/b219f80601.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/b219f80601.css" media="all">
   <title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css"><link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

And this is the script tag for bootstrap at the end of the body tag:

```html
<body>
   ...
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Note 2:
The embed codes I make and edit can only go up to v4.7.0.

Comment: Did you check whether your browser's error console contains any problem? What does inspecting that element yield?

Comment: I added the tag I used in the question. Sadly, no the browser doesn't say anything in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an accounts issue. The account hadn't been confirmed but emails with embed codes had been sent regardless.

The emails sent me to [this](https://cdn.fontawesome.com/embed-codes) address and that seems to be a limited panel that allows you to create font-awesome 4 kits. This is the UI:

[image: font-awesome cdn beta]

Once the account had been registered I was able to log into the site and access font-awesome 5 regularly and create new kits. These links start with `kit` instead of `use`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your JS link does not actually provide the CSS required to render the icon. You need to include at least the base and solid icon set CSS.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-P9vJUXK+LyvAzj8otTOKzdfF1F3UYVl13+F8Fof8/2QNb8Twd6Vb+VD52I7+87tex9UXxnzPgWA3rH96RExA7A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/solid.min.css" integrity="sha512-tk4nGrLxft4l30r9ETuejLU0a3d7LwMzj0eXjzc16JQj+5U1IeVoCuGLObRDc3+eQMUcEQY1RIDPGvuA7SNQ2w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/b219f80601.js"></script>

<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
```

Also, upon review of the CSS tag you have in your header, I think you may be trying to use FAv5 JS with FAv4 CSS.

Comment: The weird thing is I don't think I actually added the css for the icons myself. That's what got loaded in from the JS. When I was creating or tried to edit an embed code it only allowed me to go up to v4.7.0 and I can't actually select version 5.

Comment: There are separate links for [FAv4](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/get-started/) and [FAv5](https://fontawesome.com/start). Maybe you're using the v4 link?

Comment: I'm not sure what the link was but you were right in that it was a wrong one. That's the only one(s) I had access to until I realized that the account wasn't fully registered.